# Getting label name in jQuery when it gets clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a link to label in which text is `questions.label`:

```
 <%= link_to questions.label, '#', class: "set-label" ,style:"margin-right:5px; float: right;" %><br>
```

how to get that `questions.label` value in my jQuery?

```
 $(".set-label").on("click", function (e) {
 lab = $(this).text       // get the label that was clicked, but this doesnt get the text
 $(".labels").hide()      
 $(".labels."+lab).show() 
 });
```

this is the part I want to display when the label is clicked:

```
<div class="labels<%= question.label %>">
<h2> <%= question.text %></h2>
<form role="form" action="">
<div class="answer">
<input type ='text' name=""> </input>
</div>
<%= link_to "Delete", {controller: "questionnaires", action: "destroy", id: question.id %>
<% end %>
<a class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" style="float: none;margin-left: 3px;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addQuestion" id = "ansButton"  > Add Question </a>
<% end %>
</form>
</div>
```

image for div class for separated labels:

[image]

image for wardrobe label:

[image]

image for personal style:

[image]

Comment: try `$(this).text()`

Comment: Please provide plain html instead of that `<%=` stuff.

Comment: @Tanmay thats rails
<a class="set-label" style="margin-right:5px; float: right;" href="#">STYLING</a>

Comment: @summu Thanks. So `$(this).text()` will give text STYLING.  But this may breaks at `$(".labels."+lab).show()` if label contains white-space.

Comment: how label will contain white space, i will get STYLING text as it is from $(this).text() , right ?

Comment: @Tanmay yes you were right , i faced this issue now and solved it using  var lab = $(this).text().trim();

Comment: @summu There is another scenario as well. You may also face issue if text contains more than one words e.g "MY STYLING". Eventually `$(".labels.MY STYLING").show()` will not work.

Comment: yes i handles that case already by using   var lab = $(this).text().trim().replace(' ','.') , as i had that kind of labels alot